# Writing a Blackjack program, getting nullpointerEx when I tried to printout the shuffled deck

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, tostring, blackjack

Basically I tried to run deckTest() in the test program to print out the post-shuffled deck(remove the first and last comment on deckTest). All I got was nullpointerEx on the line `answer=answer+ "\n" + deck[i].toString();` in the toString method in Deck class.

But when I tried to print out the Pre-shuffled deck(with the comments on in testDeck() ) , its fine.

From the fact that the second comment in deckTest() actually display the first card of a shuffled deck, I think the shuffle at least works!

Thanks for ALL of you guys and have a great 2015!
William S

There is the test program:

```
public class TestCard
{



    public static void main ()
    {
        Card c1=new Card(0,1);
        Card c2=new Card(3,13);
        System.out.println(c1.toString());
        System.out.println(c2.toString());

    }
    public static void deckTest()
    {
        Deck d1= new Deck();
        System.out.println(d1);

        //d1.shuffle();
        //System.out.println(d1.dealCard().toString());
        //System.out.println(d1.toString());

    }
}
```

There is the deck class that it is referring to:

```
import java.util.Random;// for shuffing the cards


public class Deck
{


    private final int NUMOFCARDS= 52;
    private int numCards;

    private Card[] deck= new Card[53];

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class deck
     */
    public Deck()
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (int s=0;s<=3;s++)
        {
            for (int n=1;n<=13;n++){

                deck[c]=new Card(s,n);
                c++;    
            }
        }
        numCards=NUMOFCARDS;
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to display all of the cards in the deck
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        String answer = "";

        for (int i=0;i<53;i++)
        {

            answer= answer + "\n" + deck[i].toString();
        }



        return answer;

    }

    /**
     * returns true of the current number of cards in the deck equals to 0
     */
    public boolean empty()
    {
        return numCards==0;
    }

    /**
     * pull the bottem card from the deck
     * the variable 
     */
    public Card dealCard()
    {
        if (empty())
        {
            System.out.println("the deck has run out of cards, there will be a new,preshufffled deck to continue");
            //shuffle();  //shuffle cards
            numCards=NUMOFCARDS; //reset dealPosition for dealing new deck            
        }

        numCards--;
        return deck[52-numCards];        
    }

    public void shuffle()
    {
        Random random = new Random(); // creat a random object

        Card memory;
        int randomPosition ;
        for (int i=0;i<53;i++)
        {
            randomPosition = random.nextInt(53); // assign a number between 0 to 52 as randomPosition for shuffle
            memory=deck[i];   // store the current deck[i] card 
            deck[i]=deck[randomPosition];    //assign new card to current card 
            deck[randomPosition]=memory;    //assign current card to new card 
        }

    }
}
```

There is the Card class that the deck and test method is referring to:

```
public class Card
{
    final int JACK = 11;
    final int QUEEN = 12;
    final int KING = 13;
    final int ACE = 1;



    private int num;
    private int suit;
    final int SPADES = 0;
    final int HEARTS = 1;
    final int DIAMONDS = 2;
    final int CLUBS = 3;




    public Card(int theSuit,int theNum)
    {
        num=theNum;
        suit=theSuit;
    }

    public String showSuit()
    {
        if (suit==0)
        {
            return "Spades";
        }
        if (suit==1)
        {
            return "Hearts";
        }
        if (suit==2)
        {
            return "Diamonds";
                    }
        if (suit==3)
        {
            return "Clubs";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String showNum()
    {
        if (num==11)
        {
            return "Jack";
        }
        if (num==12)
        {
            return "Queen";
        }
        if (num==13)
        {
            return "King";
        }
        if (num==1)
        {
            return "Ace";
        }

        return ""+num;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return " "+ showNum() + " of " + showSuit();
    }



    public boolean equals(Card theCard)
    {
       return theCard.toString().equals(toString());
    }
```

Comment: Why is `Deck.deck` 53 elements long?

Comment: @immibis Perhaps removed the jokers but not "Rules for Draw and Stud Poker"?

Comment: I ask because, since you only initialize 52 elements, one of them is null. And your toString doesn't handle null.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the last card of your deck.
You have on your Deck constructor: 4 * 13 = 52 cards. Hence your array will have cards in the positions 0, 1, ..., 51. But in the toString method you iterate to the element in the 52th index, which does not exist!

Change your method toString to:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
        answer = answer + "\n" + deck[i].toString();
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Look that the method dealCard removes a card from the deck. Fixing your iteration to 52 might cause NullPointerException when you remove more cards so it's better to use numCards.

Besides that your method shuffle will also suffer from NullPointerException for the same reason. Change that method to:

```
public void shuffle() {
    final Random random = new Random(); // creat a random object

    Card memory;
    int randomPosition;
    for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
        randomPosition = random.nextInt(numCards); // assign a number
                                                    // between 0 to
                                                    // 52 as randomPosition
                                                    // for
                                                    // shuffle
        memory = deck[i]; // store the current deck[i] card
        deck[i] = deck[randomPosition]; // assign new card to current card
        deck[randomPosition] = memory; // assign current card to new card
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will try to be more defensive when I am coding next time! have a great 2015

Comment: Have a great 2015 ! Remember to accept some answer if any solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
answer=answer+ "\n" + deck[i].toString();
```

will throw the NullPointerException if deck[i] has not been initialized.  Such an exception is thrown when toString() is called with implicit parameter null.

Make sure you've initialized deck[i] before this line.

Looking at your code, it seems you aren't initializing the card at index 52.

Comment: I believe that I did initialize the deck[i] in the constructor Deck(). I did two for loops to initialize the cards inside the deck and assigned suit + number to them

Comment: you can find out for sure by printing out deck[i] immediately before that line.  Looking at your code, it seems when you shuffle() your cards, if you swap a card with one that is at a later index in the deck, your card's slot is set to null.  That is how deck[i] could become null.  But you should check this code line by line to find out exactly what/where is set to null.

Comment: There is a built in STOP function for BlueJ so I will try that to see if there is a deck[i] is null, Thx for the advice!

Comment: ok and I would try to set your card deck size to 52 and see if that error goes away.  You might end up with another error as you made other functions depend on a hardcoded deck size, so why not create a final variable DECK_SIZE = 52 and refactor that code to show DECK_SIZE or DECK_SIZE - 1instead of 53 or 52.

Comment: I actually had it called NUMOFCARDS but totally forgot to use it after creating it in the first place. I think a response from Willian also mentioned about it . I will make sure I utilize more constant in the future!

Comment: my bad, absolutely, use NUMOFCARDS!  I missed that.  And test your code every change or so to make sure you didn't introduce an error.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
/**
 * Use this method to display all of the cards in the deck
 */
public String toString()
{
    String answer = "";

    for (int i=0;i<53;i++)
    {

        answer= answer + "\n" + deck[i].toString();
    }



    return answer;

}
```

to this:

```
/**
 * Use this method to display all of the cards in the deck
 */
public String toString()
{
    String answer = "";

    for (int i=0;i<52;i++)
    {

        answer= answer + "\n" + deck[i].toString();
    }



    return answer;

}
```

As previous posters have stated, you will get a null pointer exception because you have only initialized 0-51 in the deck, but are printing 0-52 with the logic you have.

Comment: I noticed my logic doesn't make any sense , thanks for pointing that out! I recently just learned array so I still sometimes find it hard to grasp